# Try block being called twice

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, try-catch

So I have a function that retrieves data from a database, and outputs it. It's encased in a try block, so that the error from running out of rows to process is dealt with.

Here's the function that is called on load (to make the *initial output*), and called later on to update the log box.

Problem is, whenever I call the function again, it outputs the data twice. Since only the data is in the try block, and not the headers, this points to the try / catch being the issue.

Apologies for the messy / hacky code:

```
    private void NavigateRecords()
    {
        da.Fill(ds1, "LogOutput");
        textlog4.Text = "Date \t\t Time \t\t Floor\r\n";
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
            {
                DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["LogOutput"].Rows[i];
                for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= 3; i2++)
                {
                    textlog4.Text += dRow.ItemArray.GetValue(i2).ToString() + "\t\t";
                }
                textlog4.Text += "\r\n";

            }
        }
        catch { textlog4.Text += "----------------------"; }  
    }
```

This is the code that does part of the connecting, and may be of use:

```
        string sql = "SELECT * From tblLog";
        da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        NavigateRecords();
```

Initial output:

```
Date         Time        Floor
6/12        18:18:22        1       
----------------------
```

Output next time it is called:

```
Date         Time        Floor
6/12        18:18:22        1       
6/12        18:46:19        2       
6/12        18:18:22        1       
6/12        18:46:19        2       
----------------------
```

Comment: how is `NavigateRecords()` called and where is `ds1` used?

Comment: Are you using a debugger? Step through you code and you will see what's happening. There is not a problem with try/catch.

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say that the table has duplicate information in it, not that the `try` is being called twice. For the record, I'm not wild about you relying on an exception for program logic.

Comment: Do you clear ds1 before calling the NavigateRecords for the second time?

Comment: I agree that's probably an issue with `DataSet` not being cleared before subsequent uses of `Fill()` method. This is not related to the question, but please also avoid concatenating string with `+=`. Use `StringBuilder` class instead. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx.

Comment: What is it that you want to do exactly in your program as i think this needs a re-think. The main fault is the fact that your adding data into teh DataTable on top Data that already exists. you need to add DS.clear() at the beginning of your Navigate Records method, so that it clears out the dataset before you fill the Adapter each time..

Comment: @Artemix Perfect. Just needed to move the ds1 definition into the method's scope.

Comment: Where are the values `20` and `3` coming from in your for loops? Why not loop through `ds1.Tables["LogOutput"].Rows.Count`? It's terrible to rely on a catch to handle more logic. Also, it's terrible to `pokemon catch` anywhere. What happens if there's actually an exception you weren't expecting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its not an issue with your try catch , its an issue with your variables.  Clear out the variable before you add the new data to it.  I do not see your variable declared in the scope of the method so it retains the data you original put in it.