# my data is getting Saved Twice in CoreData as method is executing one time and same For another Filed is getting Blank

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

```
 func saveForHistory()  {
    let appdelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appdelegate.managedObjectContext
    let historyEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("HistoryList", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: historyEntity!,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    item.setValue(qInfo.qtitle,  forKey: "historyurls")
    item.setValue(qInfo.qImgUrl, forKey: "histiryImageUrl")
    do {
      print(item.valueForKey("historyurls"))
      print(item.valueForKey("histiryImageUrl"))
      try managedContext.save()
      historyListArray.append(item)
    } catch {
        ProjectUtility.AlertWith(self, message: "History Not Saved", Title: "Sorry")
    }
}
```

[image]

The Value I am Getting when I hit Above Method

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750464/try-block-being-called-twice

Comment: You must be calling this method twice. Set a breakpoint in the debugger.

Comment: thanks @Mundi  i Was calling this Method in for   In Loop and was getting called twice from there